# Unable to install ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the most recent version of ROS on Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo. However, when I go to terminal and enter the command "sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full", I get an error message saying "Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full". I have precisely followed the steps on [this website](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) and I have updated all my software. Is there any way I can install ROS without having to do a full downgrade of Ubuntu?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322377/unable-to-install-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-19.04/) by [harshmoney](https://answers.ros.org/users/41230/harshmoney/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-05-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As listed on the linked website Melodic supports Artful and Bionic.

It's most likely that you can compile from source on Disco, but there many be some things you need to resolve first. Alternatively you can look at using docker containers instead of downgrading your base OS.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harshmoney](https://answers.ros.org/users/41230/harshmoney/) on 2019-05-02**:
Where are the docker containers?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-03**:
[hub.docker.com/osrf](https://hub.docker.com/u/osrf/).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-05-03**:
also https://hub.docker.com/_/ros

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-05-03**:
Please accept the question with the checkbox at the left so others know that it's answered.

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-03-13**:
"ROS Melodic is available to up Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) only. Installing in newer releases requires compiling from source, something really not recommended for someone posting a question like this, if you know what I mean ;) – user880592 Jul 3 '19 at 17:11 "
[from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155722/how-to-install-ros-melodic-on-ubuntu-19-04)